Celery execution of tasks according to schedule without Django

There is an application written in Flask and there is a need to run tasks in the background, daily tasks and perform scheduled tasks.
I started using Celery+Redis for these purposes.
Implementing tasks in the background and daily tasks in Celery was not difficult, but problems arose with scheduled tasks.
Problems in particular with dynamically adding tasks, editing scheduled tasks and removing them from the queue.
I saw articles on the Internet about using `django-celery-beat`, but I would not like to use django in the project.
Please tell me, has anyone had experience implementing similar tasks in Celery and Flask without django?
